# ¿Por qué me dice que esta condición en siempre verdadera en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un objeto declarado así:

```
open class LHPsalm(
    @Ignore var theOrder: Int=0,
    var quote: String="",
    @Ignore var theme: String?=null,
    @Ignore var epigraph: String?=null,
    @Ignore var thePart: Int?=null,
    var psalm: String="",
)
{ //... }
```

La propiedad `theParte` puede ser null.

Más adelante en el código, intento verificar si esa propiedad no es igual a `0` o no es nula:

```
if(s.thePart !=0 || s.thePart != null){
    sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.partForView))
    sb.append(LS2)
}
```

Y el IDE me advierte de que esa condición es siempre verdadera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pongo primero el `null` sigue la advertencia:

```
if(s.thePart != null || s.thePart != 0){
    sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.partForView))
    sb.append(LS2)
}
```

¿A qué se debe eso y cuál sería la forma segura de verificar?

#### Edit 1

Curiosamente, si la pongo así, la advertencia desaparece:

```
            if(s.thePart!=null) {
                if(s.thePart !=0){
                    sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.partForView))
                    sb.append(LS2)
                }
            }
```

Pero creo que esto no tiene sentido, siendo que Kotlin se caracteriza por simplificar la escritura del código.

Sospecho que algo estoy aplicando mal, pero no sé qué es.

#### Edit 2

Función completa, por sugerencia de @Mateo.

```
open fun getAllForView(hourIndex: Int, calendarTime:Int): SpannableStringBuilder {
    sort()
    val sb = SpannableStringBuilder("")
    val antUnique = SpannableStringBuilder(Utils.toRed("Ant. "))

    if (theType == 1) {
        if( psalms.size == antiphons.size) {
            antiphons[hourIndex].normalizeByTime(calendarTime)
            antUnique.append(antiphons[hourIndex].antiphon)

        }else{
            antiphons[0].normalizeByTime(calendarTime)
            antUnique.append(antiphons[0].antiphon)
        }
        sb.append(antUnique)
        sb.append(LS2)
        for (s in psalms) {
            if(s.quote!="") {
                sb.append(s.quoteForView)
                sb.append(LS2)
            }

            if(s.theme!=""){
                sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.theme))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            if(s.epigraph!="" ){
                sb.append(Utils.fromHtmlSmall(s.epigraph!!))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            if(s.thePart !=null || s.thePart !=0){
                sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.partForView))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            sb.append(s.psalmForView)
            sb.append(LS2)
        }
        sb.append(Utils.toRed("Ant. "))
        sb.append(antUnique)
        sb.append(LS2)
    }

    if(theType==0 && psalms.size == antiphons.size){
        for (s in psalms) {
            antiphons[s.theOrder-1].normalizeByTime(calendarTime)
            sb.append(antiphons[s.theOrder-1].getBeforeForView())
            sb.append(LS2)
            if(s.quote!="") {
                sb.append(s.quoteForView)
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            if(s.theme!=""){
                sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.theme))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            if(s.epigraph!=""){
                sb.append(Utils.fromHtmlSmall(s.epigraph!!))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            if(s.thePart != 0 || s.thePart!=null){
                sb.append(Utils.toRed(s.partForView))
                sb.append(LS2)
            }
            sb.append(s.psalmForView)
            sb.append(LS2)
            sb.append(antiphons[s.theOrder-1].afterForView)
            sb.append(LS2)
        }
    }
    return sb
}
```

Comment: sera que si las pones al reves no pasa?? sin entender mucho de ese lenguaje, basandome en el resto (no se si hace una comprobacion optimista, o no), si la primera parte no tiro error, entonces no es nulo.. si no, la primera parte deberia tirar error por ser nulo y no poder compararlo con un numero...

Comment: @gbianchi si la pongo al revés `if(s.thePart!=null || s.thePart !=0){` me dice lo mismo.

Comment: Para.. antes de eso, no comprobaste que fuera nulo???

Comment: @gbianchi el dato se recupera de una clase `Entity` desde la base de datos y no hago ninguna comprobación cuando lo paso a la clase en la capa de datos externa. En la entidad, está definido como *nullable*: `@ColumnInfo(name = "thePart", defaultValue = "NULL") var thePart: Int?)` lo que no sé es si Room mete la cadena `NULL` por defecto cuando vienen datos nulos. Es extraño, porque siempre me deja usar el dato sin pedirme que le ponga los típicos `!!` o `?` cuando se trata de datos nulos.

Comment: @gbianchi depurando el código, lo que está pasando es que cuando viene `null` desde la base de datos lo convierte a `0`.

Comment: @Mateo agregada al final en el **Edit 2**.

Comment: Me di cuenta que no hacía falta agregar el código de la función. En este caso la documentación era suficiente para explicar lo que sucede.

Answer (score 0):

Existen 2 tipos de [igualdad](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/equality.html), estructural y referencial.

La [igualdad estructural](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/equality.html#structural-equality) determina si dos objetos son equivalentes mientras que la referencial determina si se trata del mismo objeto.

Según la documentación, la instrucción `a == b` es traducida como:

```
a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)
```

De esta forma no obtienes la típica **NullPointerException** en ninguna comparación de este estilo.

---

Consideremos el siguiente código:

```
val a = 0
if (a != 0 || a != 1)
    print("a no es 0 o 1")
```

La variable `a` es un número y puede tomar un único valor. Si `a` es 0, `a` no es 1 y la condición se cumple. De igual manera, si `a` es 1, `a` no es 0 y la condición se cumple. Por último, si `a` no es ni 0 ni 1, la condición también se cumple.

Ya que no hay que preocuparse por NPEs, el mismo análisis se puede aplicar a tu código.